# Implementation of Security PIN in asp.net identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

are there any default implementation for security pin provided by asp.net identity?
for example, when user perform certain action, security pin dialog box will be prompted and user must enter the security pin correctly for the action to be perform.

Comment: No, but why would you want that? If the security pin is compromised anyone can execute the action. Roles and permissions are a better way.

Comment: If it were a case where user forgot to log out / the other user has  the password to log in, then this security PIN could be a secondary layer before user reset password or purchase any item

Comment: You might as well just have them re-enter their password. A "pin" will be easily forgotten and/or won't be as strong.